# What's the reason for wiremock instead of Mockito in integration tests

Tags: integration-tests, junit

I enjoyed the process of writing an integration test for a system that relies on http, by mocking such end-points with Wiremock, and I feel upskilled, having wrestled with Matchers.

Now, Wiremock as a standalone server is very useful for multiple reasons but, although it has neat integration with JUnit, I don't get the point in choosing it, instead of, for example, Mockito, as a mocking framework in tests. Someone, please school me.

Comment: kindly leave a comment, explaining the downvote.

Comment: (Not my downvote but) Lots of preamble which doesn't really help the question which is "why wiremock rather than mockito"

Comment: Word, I'll edit.

Comment: I don't understand the grievance with this question, perhaps this is the wrong "forum" for questions of this type,

Comment: I am unable to "answer"" my own question, but for those interested, this provided me with food for thought: http://wiremock.org/docs/simulating-faults/

Answer (score 2):

Wiremock is designed specifically for integration testing, where Mockito is designed for unit testing.  Wiremock describes itself as a "simulator for HTTP-based API's", whereas Mockito describes itself as "a mocking framework that tastes really good."

In short, they're two entirely different use cases, despite the similarities.

Comment: thanks, though perhaps I was not clear; in terms of its use case in the testing perspective, it's not all too different.

Comment: Unit testing and integration testing (especially integration testing at the UI level) couldn't be more different.  Unit testing is straightforward; automation testing of UI's is so difficult that the usual practice is to avoid it whenever possible (in part by moving as much logic out of the UI into other classes).

Comment: but surely some service needs to be nocked out of the way, surely mockito can be used just as effectively.

Comment: I wouldn't know; I'm not an expert at these frameworks.  The way to find out is to stand up some small prototypes and see how each framework holds up.